# Why currentTimeMillis() reset to 1970

Tags: android, time, unix-timestamp, current-time

I developed an application with Android that saves a timestamp in a txt file and then uploads the file to a server so as I can check  data.
The app worked always fine but now I have some strange behavior for one telephone.
The time stamps written are e.g. 77204164, 77204290. Since the period is 200 ms more or less it means 77204 UNIX timestamp that converted is **GMT: Thursday, January 1, 1970 9:26:44 PM**. Why?
I suppose no conversion error since the app worked always fine and the code is simply:

```
String date= Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Unfortunately, the phone is far away, the only thing that I know is that the date showing to the user is ok.

Comment: Why to you divide the timestamp by 1000? 77204164 should be somewhere in 1972 don't know the exact date

Comment: You must check device date time setting first

Comment: @AlexandruSandu because the returned timestamp is in ms * 10^2, I divide by 1000 just to use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to show the date.

Comment: @AkshayPaliwal what can I learn from date time settings? As I said the user told me the date on the telephone is ok, so I suppose he didn't set 1970 as date :)

Comment: what method are you using to reconstruct the milliseconds back in to a Date obj? You're not giving us enough code and not giving us enough information.